# Bootstrap column element horizontal spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some buttons that should change their layout in the container depending on the screen size. Bootstrap grid system does that pretty well but I'd like to have some spacing between these buttons or columns. 
Buttons should span the whole width of the container.
Buttons can shorten and widen but preserve the height.[image: A quick sketch of what I mean]
I have tried:

- Adding a button margin (or wrapping in btn-toolbar class). This adds a margin widening the button and its column as a result the last button gets shoved to the next row
- Adding some padding as suggested in other topics - won't work.
- Used the col-offset class but it basically inserts a whole column worth of space which is too wide (I'd like to have about 5px of horizontal spacing)

How can I get some margins inside the column without affecting its width?

```css
button {
  //margin: 5px; //adds a margin, but pushes the third button off to the next row
  //padding: 5px; //as suggested somewhere. Won't work..
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <button type="button" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    Button A
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    Button B
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    Button C
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrap your buttons in their own divs

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <button type="button">
    Button A
  </button>
 </div> 
 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <button type="button">
    Button B
  </button>
   </div> 
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <button type="button">
    Button C
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will now give you padding from bootstraps classes col-xs-4 etc

you can apply different gutters width by size but adding padding to those classes e.g.

```
[class^="col-xs"]{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

will give you 10 pixels of padding just when the viewport is xs

finally make your buttons 100% wide

```
button{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Didn't even thought of separately wrapping these classes around each button and overriding the column padding. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
 <button type="button" class="btn-block ">
    Button A
  </button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
 <button type="button" class="btn-block">
    Button B
  </button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
 <button type="button" class="btn-block">
    Button C
  </button>
</div>
 
 
</div>
```

Comment: make it container

Comment: Make _what_ container? I don't think I follow.. Could you please provide a fiddle?